# Live streaming server with multiple Radio station

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, live-streaming, shoutcast, icecast

I want to create a live audio streaming server with muliple radio stations. I am new in this area. So what are things I have to do this. I have a dedicated server and I have installed an audio streaming server software **Icecast** in it.And I have created one station in it. It is working fine. I will have 40 radio stations for 40 different companies and expecting of total 1 million listeners . So What are the things I have do for a better streaming without any buffering and need to stream in a bitrate of 32 kbps. Whether I need to purchase some other software or anything. Please advice me on this .

Comment: 1 Million concurrent listeners? rrrright from zero into the top 10 of online stations in a day. Wake me up when you reach 1000 in a year.

Comment: this is actually not a radio like that. We are providing online radios for different companies almost 45 companies. each company have 2000-3000 employess.Each company radio will act as different stations. All these will be stream from one server.So the 1 million listners is total users of all the stations

Comment: That's only a theoretical maximum though. Not an actual concurrent load that you would ever reach. Also the concept has one major problem. If even a significant fraction of people at a company start listening, then the internet connection of that company will have a problem.

Comment: "All these will be stream from one server."  That's not something you really want to do if you can help it.  Better to buy hosting in smaller chunks so that you can split the load.  Should you have a problem on one server, not all of them go down, and it's usually cheaper to buy multiple small boxes rather than few large boxes.  Really, your operational challenges with something at this scale are not insignificant, especially since you won't really know your load until you get moving.  Tobias' response below is correct, but spread it out a bit...

Comment: This is a bit of a personal plug, but I have a cloud-style hosting service that would be good for your project.  It scales things up and down as needed so you don't have to worry about it.  All you need to do then is run some servers for your encoding.  (I've found that you can run 10-12 encoders on a $5/mo Digital Ocean box. If you really are only doing 32kbit MP3, that's probably 4 boxes total, depending on your settings.) You can read more about the hosting I offer here:  https://audiopump.co/cdn.html  If you think it's what you're looking for, e-mail me at brad@audiopump.co to set it up.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather simple.

- You configure Icecast for your expected parameters (40 source client limit, 1000 client connection limit, etc)
- You run 40 source clients in parallel that send a stream each to the Icecast server.

  - You will either need to use simple playlist driven source clients that don't do live-encoding, or you'll have to spread out the CPU load over several machines.
- You point your clients/listeners at the streams.

That's the gist. If you're looking for something beyond that, then you should be more specific in your question.